# [Html-Nodjs Express-S3]Enviar una imagen de un input file de html por medio de fetch.post a un api Nodejs Express y guardar esa imagen en un S3 de AWS

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express, amazon-s3

Quisiera enviar una imagen que obtengo de un **input type="file"** en html

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name = "image" id = "file" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<img id = "output" width="200" />
<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="post_reporte()">
```

La envío de la siguiente manera por medio de un fetch post a una api en Nodejs con Express

```
let imagenJPG;
var loadFile = function(event){
    var image = document.getElementById('output');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    imagenJPG = event.target.files[0];
}

function post_reporte(){
    let data = {
        file : imagenJPG
    }
    let url=ip+"asistencia"
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        query: JSON.stringify(data),
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers:{
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"  }
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error))
        .then(response => console.log('Success response:', limp(response)));
}
```

Y en el post de Nodejs lo recibo de la siguente manera, pero las imagenes me aparecen dañadas

```
app.post('/asistencia', (req, res) => {
    var imagen = guardarImagen(req.body.file);
});
function guardarImagen(imagen){
    var nombrearchivo = "imagen-"+uuid.v4()+".png"
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile(nombrearchivo,imagen,(error)=>{
        if(error) {console.log("error",error);}
    });
    var uploadParams = {Bucket: 'mybucket', Key: '', Body: '', ContentType: "image", ACL: 'public-read'};
    var file = nombrearchivo
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    var fs = require('fs');
    fileStream.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('File Error', err);
    });

    uploadParams.Body = fileStream;
    var path = require('path');
    var dir = "images/"+path.basename(file);
    uploadParams.Key = dir;

    var location='images/'+nombrearchivo;
    s3.upload (uploadParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
        console.log("Error en el Bucket", err);
        } if (data) {
        console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
        }
    });
    return location;
}
```

**No puedo enviar la imagen como base64 desde html a la api de Nodejs, debe ser enviada como archivo** Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Porque entonces no la envias como `multipart/form-data` en vez de enviarlo como `application/json`?

Comment: De igual manera me aparecen dañadas las imagenes

Comment: Como la manda con multipart/form-data? como la procesa en el servidor? 
Yo hago exactamente eso que ud necesita hacer (el código exacto no lo puedo compartir porque es código propietario)... pero hago uso de la librería 'express-fileupload' y accedo al archivo como `req.files.file`... si le sirve le armo mas o menos una respuesta de como yo lo uso y me funciona